# How to get a solution of a minimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

An optimization problem is formulated as

\begin{equation}
\min_{\lambda_k,p_k} \sum_{i=1}^K\lambda_k p_k\\
\begin{aligned}
s.t:&\sum_{i=1}^K\lambda_k p_k^{2/\alpha}\ge\max(\widehat{T},\widehat{\varepsilon})\\
&0\le p_k\le p_{k,max}\\
&0\le \lambda_k \le \lambda_{k,max}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where all arguements are constant except $\lambda_k$ and $p_k$. $\alpha$ is greater than 2.

I want to know whether there is an optimal solution? And when exists, how to get the solution. On the contrary, if there is not a solution, what operations are needed to transfer it to a solvable form.

Thanks a lot! :  )

Comment: To answer your first question, see Weierstrass' Extreme Value Theorem. In particular, since your feasible set is closed and bounded, there exists a solution. This looks like a pretty difficult nonconvex problem to me. The objective might be able to be transformed into a convex one by setting $\tilde{\lambda}_k = \log(\lambda_k)$ and similarly for the $p_k$ variables. For more on transforming posynomials into convex functions, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_programming. Unfortunately, I don't see any way in which the first two inequality constraints could be made convex.

Comment: There's also something a bit strange in the constraints. One of the summation constraints is redundant - if the sum needs to be greater than both $\hat{T},\hat{\epsilon}$, than assuming w.l.o.g. $\hat{T}\geq\hat{\epsilon}$, we do not require the second constraint. And the two last constraints simply mean that $\forall k: p_k, \lambda_k \geq 0$. Clearly every element is smaller than the maximum element.

Comment: @iarbel84 Thanks for your reply! There are indeed some mistakes and i have improved the formulation. :  )